# ngbAccordion doesnt open panels from activeIds array when coming from another page with router

Tags: angular, routes, accordion, router, ng-bootstrap

Can you help me in understanding why I cant display `activeIds` on `ngbaccordion` on another page while I'm using router ? (I have accordion with title name of projects, I'm going from accordion with `click` on title project, on main page, to another on another page)

I try to catch em on `OnInit`, `AfterView**` hooks with

`this.acc.activeIds = this.arr.map((el, i) => ngb-panel-${i});`

but nothing happens. It works(panels are open) only when I reload page, although `acc.activeIds` already have had array with panels to open. I think I'm doing something wrong or doesn't understand how to do with it.

Anyway with click on project and go to second-page route mine `acc.activeIds` dont have open state.

How I can fix this? Any hook cant help me or provide directive to html as `[activeIds]`, I have tried
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7g3yp5?file=src%2Fapp%2Facc-list%2Facc-list.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

also have had an answer - https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2675 , mb it can be helpful for someone